# Why pandas EMA result different with manually calculated EMA?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, stock, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to compare EMA result between pandas and manually calcaluted.

Here's the sample code `test_pandas.py` I'm using:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# Copyright 2021-  <linrongbin16@outlook.com>

"""test pandas"""

from loguru import logger
import pandas
import numpy
import math
import datetime


def _calculate_mean(data: list[float]) -> float:
    return math.fsum(data) / len(data)


def _calculate_sma(data: list[float], n: int) -> list[float]:
    return [_calculate_mean(data[max(0, i + 1 - n) : i + 1]) for i in range(len(data))]


def _calculate_ema_impl(data: list[float], alpha: float) -> float:
    n = len(data)
    result = numpy.zeros(n)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        result[i] = data[i] if i == 0 else alpha * data[i] + (1 - alpha) * result[i - 1]
    return result[-1]


def _calculate_ema(data: list[float], n: int) -> list[float]:
    alpha = 2 / (n + 1)
    result = [0.0 for _ in range(len(data))]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        result[i] = _calculate_ema_impl(data[max(0, i + 1 - n) : i + 1], alpha)
    return result


def _assert_eq(a: list[float], b: list[float]) -> None:
    from quant.common.floatings import eq

    assert isinstance(a, list)
    assert isinstance(b, list)
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        assert eq(a[i], b[i])


class TestPandas:
    data = {
        "date": [
            datetime.date(t[0], t[1], t[2])
            for t in [
                (2021, 10, 1),
                (2021, 10, 2),
                (2021, 10, 3),
                (2021, 10, 4),
                (2021, 10, 5),
                (2021, 10, 6),
                (2021, 10, 6),
                (2021, 10, 7),
                (2021, 10, 9),
                (2021, 10, 10),
                (2021, 10, 11),
                (2021, 10, 12),
                (2021, 10, 13),
                (2021, 10, 14),
                (2021, 10, 15),
                (2021, 10, 16),
                (2021, 10, 17),
                (2021, 10, 18),
                (2021, 10, 19),
                (2021, 10, 20),
            ]
        ],
        "price": [
            1.1,
            2.63,
            3.53,
            4.4,
            15.9,
            6.21,
            7.91,
            3.09,
            9.1,
            14.4,
            11.92,
            2.92,
            13.04,
            14.14,
            15.85,
            37.23,
            812.12,
            321.21,
            817.12,
            948.43,
        ],
    }

    def test_sma_and_ema(self) -> None:
        df = pandas.DataFrame(TestPandas.data)
        df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
            {
                "sma10": df["price"].rolling(window=10, min_periods=0).mean(),
                "ema10": df["price"].ewm(span=10, min_periods=0, adjust=False).mean(),
            }
        )
        df = pandas.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
        with pandas.option_context("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None):
            logger.debug(f"df:\n{df}")

        expect_sma10 = _calculate_sma(TestPandas.data["price"], 10)
        expect_ema10 = _calculate_ema(TestPandas.data["price"], 10)
        logger.debug(f"expect sma10:\n{expect_sma10}")
        logger.debug(f"expect ema10:\n{expect_ema10}")
        _assert_eq(df["sma10"].tolist(), expect_sma10)
        _assert_eq(df["ema10"].tolist(), expect_ema10)
```

Running with `pytest -s test_pandas.py`:

```
$ pytest -s test_pandas.py
============================================================================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.9, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/xxx/workspace/github/xxx
plugins: anyio-3.2.1
collected 2 items


.2021-11-29 16:24:05.765 | DEBUG    | quant.test.test_pandas:test_sma_and_ema:144 - df:
          date   price       sma10       ema10
0   2021-10-01    1.10    1.100000    1.100000
1   2021-10-02    2.63    1.865000    1.378182
2   2021-10-03    3.53    2.420000    1.769421
3   2021-10-04    4.40    2.915000    2.247708
4   2021-10-05   15.90    5.512000    4.729943
5   2021-10-06    6.21    5.628333    4.999045
6   2021-10-06    7.91    5.954286    5.528309
7   2021-10-07    3.09    5.596250    5.084980
8   2021-10-09    9.10    5.985556    5.814984
9   2021-10-10   14.40    6.827000    7.375896
10  2021-10-11   11.92    7.909000    8.202097
11  2021-10-12    2.92    7.938000    7.241715
12  2021-10-13   13.04    8.889000    8.295949
13  2021-10-14   14.14    9.863000    9.358504
14  2021-10-15   15.85    9.858000   10.538776
15  2021-10-16   37.23   12.960000   15.391726
16  2021-10-17  812.12   93.381000  160.251412
17  2021-10-18  321.21  125.193000  189.516610
18  2021-10-19  817.12  205.995000  303.626317
19  2021-10-20  948.43  299.398000  420.863350
2021-11-29 16:19:35.896 | DEBUG    | quant.test.test_pandas:test_sma_and_ema:158 - expect sma10:
[1.1, 1.865, 2.42, 2.915, 5.5120000000000005, 5.628333333333334, 5.954285714285715, 5.59625, 5.985555555555555, 6.827, 7.909000000000001, 7.938, 8.889, 9.863, 9.858, 12.959999999999999, 93.381, 125.19300000000001, 205.99499999999998, 299.398]
2021-11-29 16:19:35.896 | DEBUG    | quant.test.test_pandas:test_sma_and_ema:159 - expect ema10:
[1.1, 1.3781818181818182, 1.7694214876033056, 2.24770848985725, 4.729943309883205, 4.999044526268077, 5.528309157855699, 5.084980220063754, 5.814983816415798, 7.375895849794744, 8.407775472483964, 7.5309856833248965, 8.649579300484998, 11.19378988610481, 10.737740711835833, 15.78304720353951, 159.92362842577154, 190.0563513602728, 304.78040619379453, 421.4742170984318]
F

================================================================================================================================== FAILURES ==================================================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ TestPandas.test_sma_and_ema _________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

self = <quant.test.test_pandas.TestPandas object at 0x123a0df70>

    def test_sma_and_ema(self) -> None:
        df = pandas.DataFrame(TestPandas.data)
        df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
            {
                "sma10": df["price"].rolling(window=10, min_periods=0).mean(),
                "sma_std10": df["price"].rolling(window=10, min_periods=0).std(),
                "ema10": df["price"].ewm(span=10, min_periods=0, adjust=False).mean(),
                "ema_std10": df["price"].ewm(span=10, min_periods=0, adjust=False).std(),
            }
        )
        df2 = pandas.DataFrame(
            {
                "boll_low_sma10": df1["sma10"] - df1["sma_std10"] * 2,
                "boll_up_sma10": df1["sma10"] + df1["sma_std10"] * 2,
                "boll_low_ema10": df1["ema10"] - df1["ema_std10"] * 2,
                "boll_up_ema10": df1["ema10"] + df1["ema_std10"] * 2,
            }
        )
        df = pandas.concat([df, df1, df2], axis=1)
        with pandas.option_context("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None):
            logger.debug(f"df:\n{df}")

        expect_sma10 = _calculate_sma(TestPandas.data["price"], 10)
        expect_ema10 = _calculate_ema(TestPandas.data["price"], 10)
        logger.debug(f"expect sma10:\n{expect_sma10}")
        logger.debug(f"expect ema10:\n{expect_ema10}")
        _assert_eq(df["sma10"].tolist(), expect_sma10)
>       _assert_eq(df["ema10"].tolist(), expect_ema10)

quant/test/test_pandas.py:161:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

a = [1.1, 1.3781818181818182, 1.7694214876033056, 2.24770848985725, 4.729943309883205, 4.999044526268077, ...], b = [1.1, 1.3781818181818182, 1.7694214876033056, 2.24770848985725, 4.729943309883205, 4.999044526268077, ...]

    def _assert_eq(a: list[float], b: list[float]) -> None:
        from quant.common.floatings import eq

        assert isinstance(a, list)
        assert isinstance(b, list)
        assert len(a) == len(b)
        for i in range(len(a)):
>           assert eq(a[i], b[i])
E           assert False
E            +  where False = <function eq at 0x123a84ca0>(8.202096604377518, 8.407775472483964)

quant/test/test_pandas.py:44: AssertionError
========================================================================================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================================================================================
FAILED quant/test/test_pandas.py::TestPandas::test_sma_and_ema - assert False
======================================================================================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.75s =========================================================================================================================
```

Why after `2021-10-11`, EMA value between pandas and manually calcuation is different ?

## Update-1

When `index=9`, we have `ALPHA=2/(10+1)=0.1818` `EMA_df_9=df["ema10"][index]=7.375896`, and `PRICE_10=data["price"][index+1]=11.92`, refer to EMA formula, we will have:

`EMA_df_10 = ALPHA * PRICE_10 + (1-ALPHA) * EMA_df_9`

But in my manually implemented `_calculate_ema_impl` method, each EMA will calcualte from **index 0**, before values will be ignored.

So I guess my manually implemented EMA method is buggy.